# pyHook + pyGTK - close app on key press (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, pyhook

I want my (Python/Windows) GUI GTK window to close on key press. However, there's no reaction.
I'm a beginner and I was looking for answers in google.
My english isn't very proffesional too.
Please be patient with me.

```
import pygtk
import gtk
import pyHook

class Program:
    def QuitOnKeyPress(self):
        if pyHook.GetKeyState(81) == '1':
           gtk.main_quit()

def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.window.set_size_request(300, 300)
    self.window.show()

def main(self):
    gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    prog = Program()
    prog.main()

while 1:
    prog.QuitOnKeyPress() #Tried without () too
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
I tried to use win32api and pyGame too.
But win32api [[from here]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/) hasn't been installed, there was only win32com.
PyGame had a problem too - there was no keyboard events/modules installed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the pyHook tutorial.](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/) Your method of a while loop checking if a key is held down won't work well. Instead it should be like this:

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 81:
        gtk.main_quit()

# return True to pass the event to other handlers
    return True

# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
# watch for all mouse events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()
# wait forever
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out soon :)